# Resolution Inconsistency in Xcode Views for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xcode, resolution

Edit: re-typing same question to make it more specific.

So I have 3 classes in my program. App Delegate which contains:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.controller = [[InitialEdit alloc]initWithNibName:@"InitialEdit"];
self.window.rootViewController = self.controller;
```

Then InitialEdit:

```
-(InitialEdit*) initWithNibName:(NSString*) xibName{
     self.menu = [[DropDownMenu alloc]initWithNibName:@"DropDownMenu" size:230];
     self.menu.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 0, 100);
     self.menu.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
     [self.view addSubview:self.menu.view];
     return [self initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil];
}
```

And DropDownMenu
    -(DropDownMenu*) initWithNibName:(NSString*) xibName size:(int)size{
    //...not relevant code of buttons and no frame changes

```
 return [self initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil];

  }
```

So logically the 0 width would make the frame invisible but instead the width is around ~55 and I see that orange color. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hard to say with the given information. Do you have an example project I could see?

Comment: kindly upload an image depicting your scenario or a link to example project

Comment: Is there a specific reason for custom intiiazer with nib name? Why don't you simply override the system provided `initWithNibName:bundle:` and do your setup there? This method gets called before the view is drawn so it is the right moment for setup. Also (I hope you know this, but just for clarity sake), you can assign custom classes to views designed in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the problem lies in this line : `return [self initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil];`

What happens in your code, is you setup some things on `self` which has not been fully initialized (meaning, the `init` chain hasn't gone up to `NSObject`) and then you return a brand new instance of `InitialEdit` by calling `[self initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil]`.

The correct way to do this would be :

```
-(InitialEdit*) initWithNibName:(NSString*) xibName{
     self = [super initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil];
     if (self) {
         self.menu = [[DropDownMenu alloc]initWithNibName:@"DropDownMenu" size:230];
         self.menu.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 0, 100);
         self.menu.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
         [self.view addSubview:self.menu.view];
     }

     return self;
}
```

This of course assumes that you didn't overide `initWithNibName:bundle:` in your class. Even then, the general rule of thumb is that first line in custom initializer should assign `self` to result of other initializer, resulting at some point to a call to one of the initializers of `super`.